# Write runat="server" in javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

All I want to do is write this string `"runat='server'";` in javascript. and use that here:

```
var dropdown = "<td><asp:DropDownList ID='drpid' runat='server' DataSourceID='SqlDataSource1' DataValueField='Id' DataTextField='Text'></asp:DropDownList></td>"
```

error is this: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: So you want to use client side code to create a server side control? The server won't know about it because by the time the JS runs the server has already sent the page to the browser.

Comment: yes exactly, but the page never postback to server again.

Comment: @OMID that does not matter. once it's client side, the server will not know about the field, and won't render it. the browser will see an attribute it does not care about, and will mostly just ignore it.

Comment: oh hang on. ASP.NET is rendering the control *inside* your string definition

Comment: in fact I want add an ASP.NET element by using javascript to the page

Comment: @OMID, so, you can't _add an ASP.NET element by using javascript to the page_. Are you sure that need indeed asp element, and not simple `select` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET is rendering the control *inside* your string definition.

The output of that `<asp:DropDownList>` contains newlines, double quotes, and references to javascript functions, so it will definitely make a mess of your javascript string.

Instead, let asp.net render the dropdown somewhere else (it can even be inside an invisible div) like this :

```
<div id="hiddenthingContainer" style="display:none;">
   <asp:dropdownlist /> ... etc
</div>
```

Then, either use `document.getElementById("hiddenthingContainer")` or use jQuery or whatever dom library you prefer to get the element.

once you have it, it becomes a simple matter of getting the contents of the hidden container and presto, there's your string.

example using jQuery :

```
<div id="hiddenthingContainer" style="display:none">
     <asp:DropDownList ID='drpid' runat='server' DataSourceID='SqlDataSource1' DataValueField='Id' DataTextField='Text'></asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dropdown = $("#hiddenthingContainer").html()
});
</script>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this might not end up doing everything you want it to do. Asp.Net does a lot of stuff behind the scenes to hook up listeners, bind/render your view etc.

Comment: why you get html here if you can use element? and also get DropDown instread div

Comment: @Grundy true, you could just use the element instead of fetching it as a string.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer, but May be an infinite number of rows in the table. and of course an infinite number of dropdowns

Comment: there can never be an infinite number of rows in the table ;)